# Xamarin IOS identifying device

Tags: ios, xamarin, uniqueidentifier

I'm writing an application which will be used in an enterprise, no outsiders.
This application should fetch data from API response and display it.
Each user has his own device, Ipad and should see only the data he is the owner of.
Problem i'm facing is identifying the device/user, so that API responds with only the information the user is supposed to see.

brief example of how it should work:
App is opened -> get unique id -> attach ID to API call -> receive appropiate response -> display data

As i imagine this ID should be static and not made upon installation of the app or generated.

I've tried getting UDID, Serial, MAC,- no luck, they're deprecated. Only managed to get .IdentifierForVendor, which is unique not in the way that i need.

So here is my question, are there any other options left? 
Like fetching appleID name,email or should i make unique deployments for everyone separately?
Or a Log-in screen?

Comment: having the user login is pretty standard behavior for most apps

Comment: you could try to get the `UUID` then save it to `KeyChain` as a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unique id's will have to be set by deploying the app from MDM. For example:
https://docs.jamf.com/9.9/casper-suite/administrator-guide/In-House_Apps.html
How should the application accept those variables, i dont know. Maybe it modifies .plist when deploying.

Solution i did was enforcing device name from MDM, so that users are unable to change it - and using that as the unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a GUID for every App instance. However, apart from that you will have a hard time doing what you want.

These ways of identifying a device have been deprecated to ensure Advertisers and other malicious Apps cannot fingerprint a device easily.

If you don't want too much hassle authenticating everyone, you could apply a simpler scheme such as using a pin code, QR code, NFC tag or whatever you prefer.
However, if someone were to steal one of these enterprise devices and it would contain any secret information I would rather rely on something more secure as username and password, or even better something multi-factor.